# Import media doesn't set the artist and album for all my tracks

Tags: banshee

I've recently moved the house PC from Windows 7 to Ubuntu. I have 1000+ albums on a Lacie drive. these are catalogued: artist/album(s)/tracks - so one artist may have many albums.
When importing, some paths display the artist album properly in Banshee, but most end up as unknown artist, unknown album. So I end with a few albums properly displayed then everything else as unknown, which isn't useful.

I cannot see what the difference is between the successful paths and the failures.
It is odd - I created a test path on home as fred/album1/xx.mp3 and imported it but it came in as unknown.

I am setting the import preferences to: Album Artist/Artist
Anyone else seeing this?

Further info:

- /media/LaCie/RECORDS/Tom Waits/rain dogs/singapore.mp3 worked OK but:
- /media/LaCie/RECORDS/Tom Waits/Glitter and Doom Live Disc 1/06 Such a Scream.wav did not. (it's not the wav subscript, because they work sometimes!)

Answer (score 1):

If you have such a huge audio collection and want to tag them all, so they are recognised by Banshee, your tool of choice may be [easytag](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/easytag) [image: Install easytag]. It is very powerful and intuitive.

Comment: Thanks Jokerdino, I appreciate your response, but easytag is for editing the tag in mp3 files and suchlike, the great majority of my tracks are in wav (i.e., no tag) - I prefer the better sound quality. I want it to use the directories to recognise the artist/album like Winamp and Media Player do.